# Current feedback from MOSFET H-Bridge

Tags: microcontroller, current, h-bridge, feedback

Hi sorry for the poor schematic. I want to use a MOSFET H-Bridge to drive a linear actuator based on outputs from a microcontroller. The actuator I'm using has inbuilt limit switches so when it reaches its maximum point the switch will be toggled and there will be no current across the motor. For the program I'm writing to the microcontroller I need to know the full range of motion of the actuator, and so I was thinking of having the gate of an NPN BJT connected to the drain of M1 with its emitter going back to the microcontroller so that as long as there is current across the motor a signal will be sent back to the microcontroller, and when the limit switch is toggled the signal being sent back will stop and I will know the range of motion from that. Is this a viable option or does M1 need to be grounded for the circuit to operate as intended. If it is a viable option, how should I reduce the voltage and current so that the BJT I use can handle it?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWZ2Di.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: you may disappointed without linear feedback servo. consider any suitable encoder. Then you can optimized a,v,X profiles and minimized error against desired control. Torque , load may be not consistent  and will be temperature dependant

Comment: But as far as control is concerned you want to shunt coil on end, not open current, in order to stop immediately.

Comment: Even optical feedback would prevent and end-stop. Maybe link the LM specs and explain purpose will get you better advice

Comment: Thanks for responding I've switched to using an IC that incorporates current feedback which I should've just done in the first place :p

Comment: how do you retract motor if limit switch is open?

Comment: The limit switches are designed such that there is a return path but no forward path when the switch is open and when the actuator is no longer at maximum the switch will close so that it can be put into forward mode again. It's mechanical rather than electronic so I assume it just pushes the switch open and closed when it goes to maximum and back

Comment: plan to use a current shunt to control PWM . There are 4 states of FET bridge, FWD, REV, shunt to either rail (brake mode), Open (.coasting) When changing direction , low side switch becomes PWM input by AND XOR gates in alternate direction, and PWM low side provide cap-diode boost voltage for high side

Answer (score 1):

Just to not leave this thread in the lurch, unanswered, I will try here: Most microcontrollers have an analog-to-digital converter, many also have a built-in comparator. In either case, a low-value sense resistor in the mosfet source provides a signal that is proportional to the current through the transistor and therefore the transistor load. The concept of a current-sense resistor is illustrated [here](http://modularcircuits.tantosonline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/image1.png) as the "low-side option". A typical value of this current-sense resistor is .1 or .01 ohms. The signal output may need to be amplified a bit to properly feed the analog-to-digital converter or comparator.